# Ajax call not being pushed?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a very weird problem. My ajax .post call isn't being pushed and I have no idea why. It's working in another view just fine, but this one isn't working. I've been trying my hardest to figure it out, but I really need to get this done soon for a presentation. Any help would be wonderful!

```
@model ProjectCrux.Models.QuestionLinkToHashtag

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<h2>Details</h2>

@{
    var info = ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo;
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Details", "Question", FormMethod.Post)){

@Html.Hidden("SortField", (string)info.SortField)
@Html.Hidden("SortDirection", (string)info.SortDirection)
@Html.Hidden("PageCount", (int)info.PageCount)
@Html.Hidden("PageSize", (int)info.PageSize)
@Html.Hidden("CurrentPageIndex", (int)info.CurrentPageIndex)

<div>
    <h4>Question</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Question.Student.firstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question.Student.firstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Question.question)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question.question)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

    <div id="Answers">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">

            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.answers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.answer</td>
                    <td>@item.postDate</td>
                </tr>
            }

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < info.PageCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == info.CurrentPageIndex)
                        {
                            <span>@(i + 1)</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="#" data-pageindex="@i"
                               class="pager">@(i + 1)</a>
                        }
                    }

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".pager").click(function (evt) {
                                var pageindex = $(evt.target).data("pageindex");
                                $("#CurrentPageIndex").val(pageindex);
                                evt.preventDefault();
                                $("form").submit();
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>



        </table>
        <div class="posted">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers.answer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "answerBox" } })

            <button type="button" id="button">Post</button>

            <script>
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $(".posted").hide();
                    $.post("Create", $(".posted").serialize(), function (data, status) {
                        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    });
                    $(".posted").show(1000)
                });
            </script>

        </div>




    </div>

<p>
    <!--Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.questionId }) |-->
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
}
```

The show/hide functions I implemented just to check if the script is being executed, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean it isn't working??

you need to open this page in the web browser , hit F12 .> open developer tools, Go to Network Tab , and filter out only XHR requests.  Then click the buitton and find the request that is being sent .  the .Net framework will respond with an HTML error page if anything went wrong with the request .  As long as there actually is a controller that the request is going to you will get some type of response

I personally prefer